# Replace before String in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

Searched around and haven't found a string like mine.

```
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
```

How would I remove`ID:`so I have

```
Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
```

Then remove `Email:IP:` so it would be

```
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Input:

```
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
ID:Name:Email:IP:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
```

#### Find and replace, regex mode:

Find what: `^(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?):(.*?)$`
Replace with: `\2:\5:\6`

[image]

#### Result:

```
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
Name:Pass_Hash:Pass_Salt
```

#### Explanation

`^` Matches start of string
`.*?:` Matches any set of characters until `:`
`$` Matches end of string

`( )` is a captured value, you're replacing with the 2nd, 5th and 6th captured groups.

Comment: Excellent answer. I've always wanted to take some time to learn regex better... It'd be nice to have been able to write that up myself. ^_^

Comment: I would, but it'll have to wait until tomorrow. I hit my vote limit. =P

Answer (score 0):

Good ole Ctrl+F find and replace. Regular expressions are supported in NPP; You'll probably need to handle removing ID first, then strip out IP. I assume you're referring to a list of data, and not just the flat string?

Comment: Yeah, i have not used NP++ much at all. Whats the expression to remove : and before. The ones that came up in google remove all but the salt